# SQL - how to select rows that do not contain a certain ID

Tags: mysql

So I have the table flag_counts with the following columns:

```
flag_id content_id
1       10
2       10
2       11
```

and the following query

```
SELECT flag_id, content_id FROM flag_counts
WHERE flag_id != 1
```

and of course it returns

```
flag_id content_id
2       10
2       11
```

How can I change my query so that it returns all content_ids that were not flagged with "1". In this example, I would like the query to return only the last row of the table since the content_id "10" was flagged once with "1".

Comment: define 'last row' you can always do `order by` and `limit` or `group by`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT whatever
FROM flag_counts
WHERE content_id NOT IN (
   SELECT content_id
   FROM flag_counts
   WHERE flag_id = 1
)
```

or via JOIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.*
FROM flag_counts c1
LEFT JOIN flag_counts c2
 ON c1.content_id = c2.content_id and c2.flag_id = 1
WHERE c2.content_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

Group by the `content_id` and take only those having zero records with `flag_id = 1`

```
SELECT content_id
FROM flag_count
GROUP BY content_id
HAVING sum(flag_id = 1) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This addresses the question:  *How to change my query so that it returns all content_ids that were not flagged with "1"?*  The "clarification" is actually more confusing, because SQL tables represent unordered sets, so there is no "last" row.

If you have a separate table of content ids, then the fastest approach might be:

```
select c.*
from contents c
where not exists (select 1
                  from flag_count fc
                  where fc.content_id = c.content_id and flag_id = 1
                 );
```

For this, you would want an index on `flag_count(content_id, flag_id)`.

If you use `flag_count` instead of `contents`, then you might get duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

One of the following method can be used to solve this.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.content_id 
FROM 
    flag_counts a 
LEFT JOIN flag_counts b
ON  (a.content_id = b.content_id AND b.flag_id = 1)
WHERE   b.content_id IS NULL;

SELECT  DISTINCT a.content_id FROM flag_counts a  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM flag_counts b WHERE a.content_id = b.content_id AND b.flag_id = 1)
```